# HDRi environment & Moving camera

Tags: 3dsmax

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days and ive searched around but haven’t had any luck.

My scene is an object in the middle a camera circling the object and a Vray dome with an HDRi map. the environment i set as an instance of the HDRi map.

My object is sitting on a Matte plane for a shadow and absolutely no other geometry.

The problem im having is that when i render out the animation my object seems to dislocate itself from the environment and doesn't stay in place. Is there way to link the HDRi map to the camera movement? Any help is appreciated.

video
https://streamable.com/mwq3ue

Answer (score 0):

HDRI env maps are spherical maps, they contain no 3D data. In your Env map, there is a Ground that you can see but that is only a "photo", therefore, if you move your camera forward, the ground won t match the perspective, since it has no 3d information. The only fix would be : 1 don t matte your floor object, use a ground texture, with a Fresnel applied on the opacity so it disolves with distance, blending with the env map.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCjxL-XpC1w&t=260s check from 1:47 how was he able to do it ?

Comment: he s using 3ds max HDRI tools, it has an inbuilt rad floor function (it s a slider on top of the 3d viewport) that you can move to the right, and that projects the HDRI on a ground. Man if you are learning, don t learn 3Dsmax, just go straight to Maya, houdini or even Blender. Anyway, if you don t have these HDRI tools, what it does is, it simply creates a half sphere (with a flat ground), it projects the env map on the sphere (since it s half, it contains a floor)

Comment: i have maya. but am working on something and 3d max is good i like it. i am stuck as this stage to be honest.

Comment: are u using the HDRI tools as he made them in the video ? it explains it all .. BTW stack overflow is a coding forum :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsAUfQlZH_w here it explains it all, in a very simple way, just follow this.

Comment: nice one buddy but this is for blender dam

Comment: sorted i think. simple option was unticked ground projection in vraybitmap